# Stored Procedure to pass column name as parameter

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE table TaskState (id int NOT NULL, TodoTask text ,ContinueTask text, CompleteTask text ,PRIMARY KEY (id)) ;

  CREATE PROCEDURE movedata(idp int,fromto  VARCHAR(20), tofor VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
update TaskState set tofor= fromto where id=idp;
update TaskState set fromto='add' where id=idp;
END //
```

here i am moving data one column to another column and i want to varchar variable will have column name but it is failed   how can i make query  because i don't want to create separate query for each transaction  how can i create query for it

in database there are three + one ID column integer for pointing .  in three column one column  will have  data and remaining null here i just moving data one field to another

so i need a query which will provide column name at runtime

Comment: Tablename cannot be taken from parameter/variable. Use dynamic Sql (prepared statement).

Comment: thank you akina can you please tell me about it    
i am new in this wolrd

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE movedata(idp int,fromto  VARCHAR(20), tofor VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
SET @sql := CONCAT( 'update TaskState set ', tofor, '=', fromto, ',', fromto, '=\'add\' where id=', idp);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: call movedata(9300,'TodoTask','CompleteTask');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=CompleteTask where id =?9300' at line 1

Comment: @MohammedShaikh https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2636feb5c56b4739330d3f53ae3a046

Comment: @MohammedShaikh *near '=CompleteTask where id =?9300' at line 1* - such substring cannot be produced by my code.